# C: The scanf() function is not working as it should

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am having trouble with the `scanf()` function. When I compile and run this code

```
        int ID;
        char* name = NULL;
        char sex;
        float quiz1;
        float quiz2;
        float midscore;
        float finalscore;
        float totalscore;

        printf("please enter the student information.\n");
        printf("ID: ");
        scanf("%i", &ID);
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf(" %s", name);
        printf("Sex: ");
        scanf(" %c", &sex);
        printf("Quiz mark(first semester): ");
        scanf(" %f", &quiz1);
        printf("Quiz mark(second semester): ");
        scanf(" %f", &quiz2);
        printf("Mid-term score: ");
        scanf(" %f", &midscore);
        printf("Final score: ");
        scanf(" %f", &finalscore);
        printf("Total score: ");
        scanf(" %f", &totalscore);
```

What I get is :

> ID: 5
>   Name: alex
>   Sex: Quiz mark(first semester): Quiz mark(second semester): Mid-term score: Final score: Total score:

Can someone explain me what's going on?

Comment: when calling the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  When using the '%s' input/conversion specifier, always use a 'max length' modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.  Remember that each of these inputs was trailed with a newline char sequence. the '%s' is problematic about handling white space.  and the '%c" will input the newline from the prior entry,  each of these can be fixed by using a leading space in the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point of

```
 scanf(" %s", name);
```

`name` is NULL (i.e., it points to *invalid memory location*), and using that as the argument to `%s` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `name` before you can use that to hold the input.

Comment: for example declare it like `char name[100];`

Comment: @infixed that way, `name` won't be a pointer anymore, but you're correct, too.

Comment: I usually lexically consider bare `name` to be the same as `&name[0]`, and therefor remains a pointer.  Certainly it is not a pointer _variable_ anymore.  You can't rebase it by using it as a lvalue.  But still a pointer you can use as an rvalue.

Comment: @infixed  when `name` is an array like `char name[100]`, a weakness to "consider bare `name` to be the same as `&name[0]`" occurs with `sizeof()` as `sizeof name != &name[0]`.

Comment: @chux While that's true, `sizeof` isn't evaluating it as a plain rvalue, its using special behavior defined for arrays.    for instance `sizeof (name)` evaluates as 100. because sizeof treats name as an array type.  but `sizeof (name+0)` evaluates as 4, because `sizeof` then treats it as a pointer expression.  (for the particular compiler I tried it on. YMMV)

Comment: @infixed Hmmm  interesting. I see it the other way around: `sizeof name` is not special, it is simply the operator acting on the object, which happens to be an array.  `name+0` is special behavior for arrays as that converts the array to the address of the first element of the array and adds 0. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @chux.  I suppose if I was playing spec-lawyer, I'd appeal to '
6.2.2.1 Lvalues and function designators
 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a character string literal used to initialize an array of character type, or is a wide string literal used to initialize an array with element type compatible with wchar_t, an lvalue that has type "array of type'' is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array and is not an lvalue. '

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
char* name = NULL;
```

You need to assign some memory to the pointer before writing any data. You can either assign some space statically or dynamically:

```
char name[10];
char *name2;
name2 = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```